# Interactive pdf- not displaying on website

Tags: asp.net, pdf, web-applications

Why does the interactive pdf not display on the website. The file displays ok in dev.

Get HTTP 400 bad request, even though the url is correct

Comment: Please provide some more detail.  Also, how does this relate to ASP.NET?

Comment: asp.net is what the pdf link is in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this.
Not sure the reason, but changing the filename fixed the problem.

Has anyone encountered this before. What causes this?

Comment: What was the filename before and after you changed it?

Comment: P&PIP_Registration_Form_FINAL.pdf, I changed it to Registration_Form.pdf.
That was the only thing I changed!

Comment: The ampersand was the problem.